# Delete all rows except first N rows within each time interval group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a table:

| ID | DateTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-30 01:02:03 |
| 1 | 2022-01-30 01:34:03 |
| 1 | 2022-01-30 02:59:03 |
| 2 | 2022-01-30 01:02:03 |
| 2 | 2022-01-30 01:34:03 |
| 2 | 2022-01-30 02:59:03 |

And I would like to delete all the rows except for 1 every hour for each unique ID. So the resulting table would look like:

| ID | DateTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-30 01:02:03 |
| 1 | 2022-01-30 02:59:03 |
| 2 | 2022-01-30 01:02:03 |
| 2 | 2022-01-30 02:59:03 |

Comment: What have you considered and tried? You start with a select to identify the rows you don't want, then turn it into a delete.

Comment: If you have a question, you need to ask it as well as include what you've tried so far.

Comment: @dmg, do you really want to delete the row in the "middle"? or what's your logic of deletion

Comment: Are you sure you want to "delete all the rows except for 2 every hour"? Your resulting sample is keeping only one per each hour per unique ID.

Comment: Oh, it's first row every hour is kept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cte (they could be used for delete) and window functions:

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (
         partition by id, cast(datetime as date), datepart(hour, datetime)
         order by datetime
    ) as rn
    from t
)
select * -- delete
from cte
where rn > 1
```

Change `select *` to `delete` once you're sure that the query contains the correct rows.

Comment: thanks, this does partition the rows nicely by an hour